# Shortcode with PHP issue "Undefined index"

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm creating a shortcode to display images in different sizes: large, small and regular. The user has the option to set `large="true"` or `small="true"` when writing the shortcode to output the right image code.

I have a PHP issue with the following message on the Front End when the shortcode is active and the option `large` and/or `small` aren't set to true or false:

*Notice: Undefined index: large in /wp-content/themes/mysite/functions.php on line 1449*

*Notice: Undefined index: large in /wp-content/themes/mysite/functions.php on line 1451*

Line 1449 is `if( $atts['large'] == true )` and line 1451 is `if( $atts['small'] == true )`

Here is the PHP code of the shortcode:

```
add_shortcode ("img", "img_output");
function img_output($atts, $content="null") {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'large' => false,
            'small' => false,
            'url' => ''
    ), $atts ));
    if( $atts['large'] == true ) {
        return '<img src="' . $url . '" class="img-large" width="100%" height="auto" />';
    } else if( $atts['small'] == true  ) {
        return '<img src="' . $url . '" class="img-small" width="100%" height="auto" />';
    } else {
        return '<img src="' . $url . '" class="img-regular" width="100%" height="auto" />';
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because if the user enters `large="true"`, then `$atts['small']` isn't defined. The normal solution is to use `shortcode_atts()` to set default values for the parameters, but you're not putting the result of `shortcode_atts()` into `$atts`, you're just just extracting it. This means that `$small` will be defined, but `$atts['small']` won't be.

The proper way to solve this is to put `shortcode_atts()` into a variable:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'large' => false,
        'small' => false,
        'url' => ''
), $atts );
```

On a side note, it having a single `size=""` attribute, with `small` or `large` as possible values, instead of separate attributes for each size, would probably be easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob! Your solution works perfectly. The `size=""` attribute is a good solution too I totally agree.